# When and how does magnetism pass through bodies?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I've seen a video by Walter Lewin in which the magnetic pull between two wires is unaffected when an aluminum plate is situated between them.

Can you explain what materials let magnetism pass through and how this can happen? does that give clues on the nature of magnetism? I originally thought Lewins says that conductiveness is the key factor, but I discovered that superconductors don't let it pass

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic fields are affected by all materials, but only very weakly unless the material is ferromagnetic (like iron and nickel and permanent magnetic materials) or a strong diamagnet (like a superconductor).

We do understand the nature of magnetism very well, unfortunately, a real explanation requires quantum mechanics. There is no classical theory of magnetism and one can prove mathematically that there can't be.

Superconductors, in particular, are quantum mechanical in nature. That they are forming macroscopic diamagnets (materials that are expelling the magnetic field from their volume) can be explained with the eddy currents that get induced in the superconductor when it is brought into a magnetic field. Since the eddy currents never diminish and because they always act against the magnetic field that is causing them, they keep "pushing" the magnetic field away from the superconductor.

Aluminum plates can also develop eddy currents, but unlike in a superconductor these decay very quickly and the magnetic field can penetrate.

At the atomic level we have similar phenomena: a magnetic field can induce a tiny current in an individual atom, which then becomes diamagnetic, i.e. it repels magnetic fields. Water does this and carbon and you can find experiments that demonstrate this on the internet.

Finally there are atoms that have magnetic moments and behave like elementary magnets. When these magnetic atoms are attracting each other strongly, many of them can point in the same direction, which is called a "magnetic domain". These domains can be so large that they are visible in a microscope if the sample has been prepared suitably:

[image]

Materials in which the magnetic domains re-orient themselves in an external magnetic field are ferromagnets. If almost all of them spontaneously point in the same direction, then we have a permanent magnet. There are many ways in which the microscopic properties of magnets can be studied (e.g. by measuring the magnetization as a function of temperature, by scattering neutrons on magnets etc..) and we have learned a lot about the structure of these materials and how they interact with magnetic fields. We are therefor fairly sure that we understand how many magnets and magnetic materials "work", but the research is far from finished, as the continuous development of ever higher performance magnetic materials proves.